# Ember-restless with Ember 2.0

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

Problems I have with ember are related to [ember-restless](https://github.com/bustlelabs/ember-restless) module I would like to use instead of ember-data(I have completely removed data module from my project).
I am still learning ember so I am not sure if this has something with latest version, or with programming style, but I saw that in Ember 2.0 we would write

```
export default RL.Client.create({
  adapter: App.RESTAdapter
});
```

instead of

```
App.Client = RL.Client.create({
  adapter: App.RESTAdapter
});
```

but it seems that my client is then not recognised(if I write it in first way), as get request are made to localhost instead of url I specified in RESTAdapter class.

Second problem I have is that

```
import RL from 'ember-restless';
```

does not work for me, it says that module 'ember-restless' could not be found.

Any help would be appreciated, as I have been struggling with this for some time.

**UPDATE**

I changed importing syntax to following, and here's the situation:

```
import { Client } from 'ember-restless';
```

If a put this import in my model class, I am getting following error in js console:

```
Error: Could not find module 'ember-restless' imported from 'ember-test2/models/pol'
```

However, if I remove import from model class, leave adequate imports in RESTAdapter and Client definitions, there are no errors, but services are called on localhost:4200 instead on localhost:8080.

I will provide my definitions from js files here:

models/pol.js

```
import { RL } from 'ember-restless'; // imports entire library

var Pol = RL.Model.extend({
  idPol: RL.attr('integer'),
  naziv: RL.attr('string')
});

Pol.reopenClass({
  resourceName: 'pol/e'
});

export default Pol;
```

adapters/application.js

```
import { RL } from 'ember-restless';

export default RL.RESTAdapter.create({
  host: 'http://localhost:8080',
  namespace: 'zareps'
});
```

adapters/client.js

```
import {RESTAdapter} from '../adapters/application';
import {Client} from 'ember-restless';

export default Client.create({
  adapter: RESTAdapter
});
```

routes/list-pol.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Pol from '../models/pol';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Pol.find();
  }
});
```

Comment: Make sure you have latest version of ember-restless installed.

Comment: Yes, I checked, currently using 0.7.10